# Can not be obtained permission publish_stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know what to do.
I have experience in writing applications on FB.
I don't understand this problem.
I have simple app. (https://apps.facebook.com/gecko_terrarium/)

```
require './libraries/facebook/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(...));

$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
?><html><body>
<?php 
if($user) { 
  try { ?> <a href="#" onclick="fbLogin()"> Login</a> <?php
    $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
    print_r($permissions);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) { ... }
else {
   echo("<script> top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=111111111&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/gecko_terrarium&state=" . md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)) . "&scope=publish_stream'</script>");
exit;
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() { ....}

function fbLogin() {
   FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
         console.log("user gave permission");    
      } else {
         console.log("user did not give permission");
      }
   }, {scope:'publish_stream'});
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

When for the first time, a window pops up with permissions no questions about publishing.
When I click on the login button, no window pops up. A console is the inscription 'user gave permission'

But on the screen you can see that you do not have such permission.

I do not know how to explain it.

Can You help me?

Comment: Why are you using two different ways of triggering login here anyway? And btw., if I decline even basic access to your app, it keeps redirecting to the login dialog over and over again – that is something you shouldn’t do; if users decline login, then you should _explain_ to them how they would benefit from login and granting the permission you ask for, and only send them through login again if they actively request so (f.e. by clicking on a link/button). Facebooks doesn’t look too kindly on apps doing what you’re doing at the moment – sometimes they even show a form to _report_ apps for this.

Comment: Because I wanted to show that something is wrong. It keeps redirecting to the login dialog over and over again only for now. It is simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the Facebook SDK library. They do have a sample login with permissions you want to try. The correct authorization is not `publish_stream`, but `publish_actions`, by the way. The url I use for that authorization is `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=$SOME_APP_ID&redirect_uri=$YOUR_URL&scope=publish_actions`.

N.B.: Remember to migrate to the [Version 2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0), because the old graph API will be on for less than one year.
With the new API, you'll have to request explicit permission to publish actions. To do that, visit https://developers.facebook.com, select your app in the Menu, click on "Status and Review", scroll down the page, submit your action for approval (you have to give them a rationale of the action and how you use it to enhance user experience, working examples they can test, etc.)

Comment: I understand. Does this mean that there will be no permission publish_stream? Only publish_actions?

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1389117254661198&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/gecko_terrarium&scope=publish_actions`
works :)

Comment: yup :) glad I was helpful